# Change name interface

Tags: interface, linux

Sorry for my English....

I want to change the interface name, what I don't know sure the steps....

First I should know my **interface name** and **mac** from it,

```
ip a
```

Seconds, down my **NetworkManager**,

```
sudo ip link set dev enp31s0 down
```

rename the device name, I'll change to **hallo0**.

My question, what is the difference between used,

1-

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

and write on this file

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug  hallo0
iface hallo0 inet dhcp
```

2-

With **udev**

```
sudo /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules
```

and write on this file,

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", NAME="hallo0="
```

What from the Two possibilities should use?

Can please someone help with this question, Thanks!

Comment: It's not a question that related to NE. Ask it on another SE site like [Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions).